# Almacenar output de una línea de comando con Python

Tags: python, shell, proceso

He estado haciendo algunas cosas con shell para **sacar los datos de la batería asignada a mi portátil**. He utilizado, por ejemplo, el siguiente comando para mostrar el vendedor de la batería:
`data=$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1 | grep "vendor:" | sed -r 's/vendor:"?([^"]+)"?/\1/')`

De entrada no tengo mucha idea de lo que hace en el `sed`, me desconcentra bastante. Lo único que sé es que funciona y el output sale bien.

Ahora os planteo un par de dudas:

1. Pretendo sacar más datos de ese comando (como por ejemplo "status"). ¿Cómo debería modificar el comando de arriba para recoger los dos datos?
2. Una vez conseguidas las dos variables por output, ¿cómo hago por Python para recogerlas con un Array?

Intenté hacer algo similar a un `bat_data = subprocess.Popen([...])`, pero tampoco sé cómo incluir ahí mi comando.

Comment: recuerda que Stackoverflow en español funciona con una pregunta - una respuesta. Lo que entiendo, es que tu problema es que no has leído la documentación de sed (`man sed`) ni de `popen`. Te recomiendo que lo hagas. Que intentes algo y que hagas preguntas específicas, una cada vez.

Comment: Como te dice @toledano, es mejor que separemos por un lado lo que concierne a `sed` y por otro lo que tiene que ver con `subprocess.Popen`. Cuando lo hagas buscamos una respuesta a ambas dudas :)

Comment: Añade una salida tipo del comando `upower ...` para que te podamos ayudar. Además, separa mejor en dos preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Por las negritas de tu pregunta, entiendo que, pese al título de ésta, lo que estás preguntando en realidad es cómo obtener los datos de tu batería, y que los comentarios sobre sed y Popen son ejemplos de la estrategia que has intentado seguir.

En lugar de llamar al comando `upower` mediante Popen puedes comunicarte con él usando `DBus`.

Suponiendo que tengas instalado el paquete `pydbus` (por ejemplo mediante `pip install pydbus`):

```
>>> import pydbus
>>> bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
>>> bat = bus.get('.UPower', '/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0')
>>> bat.Vendor
'SANYO'
>>> bat.Percentage
73.24519987409506
```